# How to interpoate var from environment?

Tags: shell

Say I have a json file that containers a var:

a.json

```json
{"hello": "$WHO"}
```

And I have `WHO` in environment: `export WHO=world`. I want to interpolate a.json from env and generate a new json file:

```json
{"hello": "world"}
```

Is there a pure shell way to archive that?

Comment: Which shell? bash/zsh/fish or ash?

Comment: `export WHO=world; envsubst < a.json > b.json`